# Working with Access DataBase

Tags: .net, ms-access

I am using access as DB for my application, I know Access has the issue when more then 1 user try to update or insert the record into the DB at same point.

Just wanted to know, in this scenario how should I go. I have no other choice then using Access DB. Can I check if the DB is locked wait for some time and then try attempting like things.If yes pls let me know how to do that.

I am using ASP.net c#

Comment: Important: "THE" records as in "the SAME record", or just "A" record? As Remou mentions below, multiple users editing different records is not a problem when using Access.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid your information is incorrect. There is no problem with multiple users when the database is properly set-up. You may wish to consider something other than Jet/ACE if you have more than 30 users regularly updating data.

Comment: what do you mean by setting database properly, pls share

Comment: Access is a rapid application database development tool that uses Jet/ACE as its database. This means that the data should be in a separate Access file to the forms etc. You do not seem to be using an Access front end, so this should not be a problem for you. After that, I think you are into the same problems you might have with any database / font-end set-up.

Comment: You might like to read: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-sharing-an-access-database-on-a-network-mdb-HP005240860.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Access or more correctly JET does not have an issue with more than 1 user editing a DB, it would not be much of a database product if it did! You do however have to be careful not to lock things longer than you should or put too much strain on it however for many smaller applications it is an excellent choice. I have personally had JET backed applications handle a user base of about 30 active users with no problems